# Is there any site where i can found good documentation of wp-ecommerce plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-wp-e-commerce

**There is no good documentation in the plugin official site**

I am trying to making a web shop in WordPress with wp-ecommerce pluign. But i don't find any good documentation in the web. Even the official site for the plugin is not helping.

Do you know any site or good tutorial about the wp-ecommerce plugin? I will really appreciate if you can share your personal experience with me.

Comment: I hear you loud and clear on this question.

Comment: @Sisir please stop flagging this for deletion. There is nothing wrong with the question and it very well might get more useful answers over time.

Answer (score 2):

When i first used it I followed  the tuts up ate YouTube, here are a few good ones that I have bookmarked:

[Installing and Setting up WP-eCommerce WordPress Plugin - Pt: 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqCtIWmkyfo)

[Installing and Setting up WP-eCommerce WordPress Plugin - Pt: 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ea9uIbMDK38)

[profile with helpful videos](http://www.youtube.com/user/RoseAppleMedia)

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for the WP e-Commerce Plugin can be found at: http://docs.getshopped.org

Answer (score 1):

The below are the sites which will be more helpful throughout your wp ecommerce projects

It's official site:
http://docs.getshopped.org

And further documentation you can visit:
http://www.visser.com.au/wp-ecommerce/documentation/